# node cannot find npm install path, even though it's the default

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

Simply, trying to

```
npm install -g something
```

something and in `node`

```
let c = require('something')
```

says that it

```
Cannot find module 'something'
```

However, I don't think I've messed around with any node/npm paths.

I can fix this by running

```
export NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g)
```

*(which is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`)*

But I am wondering why I have to do this in the first place.  What is the default `NODE_PATH` that `node` is looking at, that I am changing to `npm root -g`?

I'm on macOS Catalina running the latest versions of `npm` and `node`

To summarize, my question is just about why this behavior is happening.  I already have a described the workaround for this, but you would think that `node` would use `npm root -g` as its default global req path by default.

Comment: Maybe geting rid of your global modules and set it up again helps, though not best solution

Comment: I followed the first answers responses to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) and tested again before posting this